# Microsoft Access 2007: save relative directory path in database table

Tags: ms-access-2007

I created a table with column "Directorypath" and a form with an input field for "Directorypath". When I create new database entry with the form and write something in the "Directorypath"-field (form-mode), the input is correctly stored in my table.

But in this field I want to store the relative path from my directory, so I wrote "=[Application].[CurrentProject].[Path]" (form-edit-mode). In the form-mode the path in the inputfield is shown correct but when I want to save the new entry, every other fields are saved but the "Directorypath"-field is empty (in database).

What should I do to save the path in database? My field has the fieldtype "text".

Hope anyone could help me!

Comment: I got it! I added a new event procedure for my form (beforeUpdate) and wrote Me![TableFieldname] = Me![Formfieldname] and it works!